# How to save an image generated by a php script?

Tags: php, image, barcode

I have a 3rd party php file that generates barcodes, called barcode.php.

When I want to generate a new barcode, I call that script, like this:

```
<img alt="testing" src="barcode.php?text=455555442233&codetype=Code25" />
```

Is there an easy way to save the image that is generated onto the server, without modifying the barcode.php script?

Comment: Yes of course, the data to be sent could also be written to disk. Since you neither provide any PHP code nor give detailed information, no adequate help targeting your environment is possible.

Comment: What php code would you want?  The php code in barcode.php that I don't want to modify?

Comment: Yes, the some code snippet of barcode.php would be necessary. Very likely it will have to be modified. Is there a special reason not to touch it? Some link to a larger open source library could also help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = 'barcode.jpg'; //file name to write to include location if needed
$current = file_get_contents('http://yoursite.com/barcode.php?text=455555442233&codetype=Code25');//read the created file
file_put_contents($file, $current);//write it
```

using the external url here may be sub-optimal depending on circumstances

Comment: This would throw a warning "failed to open stream", since there is no file named "barcode.php?text=455555442233&codetype=Code25". The file name is "barcode.php" and `file_get_contents` won't execute the script. The PHP code will be stored when opened without parameters.

Comment: It creates an image file as expected, but it's 0 bytes.  Still points me in the right direction though.

Comment: mea culpa, forgot a little something

Comment: A file of course is created due to `file_put_contents`. Since `file_get_contents` can **not** find the file name specified, the return value stored in `$current` will be `false` and by automatic string conversion evaluated to an empty string `""`.